# Identify "Character space Character"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm needing to identify all records within FirstName that contain values such as A & B or B C

Is there a way I could go about identifying these records? I have this currently, but it doesn't quite get me there:

```
select * from #temp
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%[a-z] [a-z]%' or
FirstName LIKE '%[a-z] & [a-z]%'
```

Sample Code:

```
Create table #temp
(
    FirstName varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp
(
    FirstName
)
select
    'Mary Smith'
union
select
    'John'
union
select
    'Bob'
union
select
    'Bruce'
union
select
    'Sally'
union
select
    'A & B'
union
select
    'B C'

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: @DaleBurrell - no, just tried regular expressions so far without quite getting to where I need.

Comment: Sorry @DaleBurrell , but my query also returns Mary Smith when it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks @DaleBurrell, feel free to offer that as a solution and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the wildcard character from your `like` expression (%) it will match your current test data e.g.

```
select *
from #temp
where FirstName like '[a-z] [a-z]'
or FirstName like '[a-z] & [a-z]';
```